# How do I choose a value for a numbered list to start at?

Tags: adobe-indesign

When you have a numbered list, you can simply right-click and choose 'restart numbering' to make it start at 1 (if it doesn't already). How do I choose a value to start at, say I want to start a list at 14, without changing the paragraph style itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- After making the paragraph style with the numbered list, select all
  the text for the second list
- From the **Paragraph Panel Menu**, choose **Bullets and Numbering**
- Create a **New List**, level **2**
- In **Mode** choose **Start At** and type a number
- Change the mode to **Continue from Previous Number**
- Optional: make a new paragraph style with this new list numbered paragraph

[image: List]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for this answer. Works great, except every bullet got the same number as the first one. I fixed that manually: Put cursor in front of second bullet, press delete to put it at the end of the first bullet, then press return to put it back as a separate bullet, this time with the proper number. Did the same for all the other bullets.
Maybe there's an easier way, but at least it worked!